Workflow that sends Dependabot PR links to Slack only works manually
I've made a pretty basic workflow that is supposed to post a message with a link to the PR whenever Dependabot creates a new vulnerability/dependency update PR (and then update the original message when the PR is merged). This action triggers manually just fine (albeit without the link since it wasn't auto-generated), but for some reason it isn't posting anything to the Slack channel when Dependabot does create a new PR. The secret has been added to the normal repo actions as well as the Depedabot secrets as well.
name: Dependabot PR Notification to Slack

on:
  pull_request_target:
    types: [opened, reopened]
    branches:
      - 'dependabot/**'
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  pull-requests: write
  actions: write
  repository-projects: write

jobs:
  Slack-PR-Notification:
    name: Slack PR Notification
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Slack Notification
      uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.25.0
      id: slack
      with:
        payload: |
          {
            "text": "New ${{ github.repository}} Dependabot PR Available for Review: ${{ github.event.pull_request.html_url}}"
          }
      env:
        SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL }}
        SLACK_WEBHOOK_TYPE: INCOMING_WEBHOOK
    - uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.25.0
      if: ${{ github.event.pull_request.merged }}
      with:
        update-ts: ${{ steps.slack.outputs.ts }}
        payload: |
          {
            "text": "PR has been merged. Thank you!",
            "attachments": [
              {
                "pretext": "Merge complete",
                "color": "28a745",
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "title": "Status",
                    "short": true,
                    "value": "Completed"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
      env:
        SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL }}
        SLACK_WEBHOOK_TYPE: INCOMING_WEBHOOK

I've tried a few things, including  if: ${{ github.actor == 'dependabot[bot]' }} but many of the Stack Overflow posts and other docs/articles either use outdated/old action packages or don't accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Workflows triggered by Dependabot are subject to a few constraints:

They have access to a separate set of secrets, not the usual ones. Dependabot secrets are configured at the repository level at https://github.com/ORG/REPO/settings/secrets/dependabot, and at the organization level at https://github.com/organizations/ORG/settings/secrets/dependabot. Make sure the SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL secret is set there.
They default to read-only permissions on the GITHUB_TOKEN. You have to set any required write permissions explicitly, though in this case, the workflow doesn't require any.
When triggered on pull_request_target, if the base ref was created by Dependabot, permissions are read-only and no secrets are available. You have to change the trigger to, e.g., pull_request in that case.

Documentation, from Automating Dependabot with GitHub Actions:


GITHUB_TOKEN has read-only permissions by default.
Secrets are populated from Dependabot secrets. GitHub Actions secrets are not available.

For workflows initiated by Dependabot (github.actor == 'dependabot[bot]') using the pull_request_target event, if the base ref of the pull request was created by Dependabot (github.actor == 'dependabot[bot]'), the GITHUB_TOKEN will be read-only and secrets are not available.
These restrictions apply even if the workflow is re-run by a different actor.


Oh interesting - I had the secrets set at the repo-layer but not the org layer. I will get that added and update the original post if anything changes.

@AshtonBecher If you had the webhook secrets as an org-level secret for dependabot, and the repo had access to it, it should have worked already. Also, repo-level secrets override org-level secrets.

Ok so then the issue isn't secret-related then, yeah? Since I was able to manually kick off the Action run and see the Slack post just fine - I'm pretty new to workflows in general, do I need to change the permissions in the workflow like this:
permissions:   pull-requests: write   issues: write   repository-projects: write

@AshtonBecher When you start a workflow manually, it doesn't use the dependabot secrets, so it might still be secrets related. Dependabot-triggered workflows also have read-only permissions, so you have to explicitly set the required permissions, good point; I'll add that.

@AshtonBecher You don't even need the checkout step in your workflow, you're not doing anything with the repository contents.

Understood, I will remove that - appreciate it.
For sake of testing, I added types: [opened, reopened, labeled, edited, ready_for_review, closed] to the action, but even after merging that change, that action still didn't get triggered when I added a label or closed/reopened a Dependabot PR. I'm seeing lots of issues on Github about Dependabot-triggered workflows having issues with secrets, but my workflow file seems to be using all the fixes/workarounds I'm seeing from official Dependabot devs...

@AshtonBecher To troubleshoot, you can look at the workflows logs: Under "Set up job", "GITHUB_TOKEN permissions" shows the effective permissions, and on the Slack notification step, check the value of the secret in the environment: is it masked (***) or empty?

Looks fine to me - at least as this workflow is concerned, no?
GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions   Actions: write   Metadata: read   PullRequests: write   RepositoryProjects: write
Secrets look good, too:
env: SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: ***

@AshtonBecher But the Slack message is not posted?

Correct. Manual runs work fine but any action that would kick it off automatically does not trigger

@AshtonBecher The repo isn't public per chance, is it?

it isn't, unfortunately - sorry. I do appreciate your time and help, thus far

Finally got it working - I changed the on: command to simply be 'pull_request:` instead of what it is in the original post

@AshtonBecher Oh, pull_request_target messed it up? Interesting.

@AshtonBecher Ah, that's actually in the docs! I'll add it to the answer.
